# Expected null to deeply equal [Array (1)]

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, cart

just a brief question. I've been struggling to figure out what this error in javascript actually means: "Timed out retrying: expected null to deeply equal [Array (1)]

I'm basically working on a LocalStorage Shopping Cart and my code is actually based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uR3r3GJvQDY&t=417s

It's pretty much very identical. The code perfectly works on my system without any errors but as soon as I upload it to my university's server on which the code undergoes certain tests I receive the above-named error. It also doesn't really indicate in which line of the code the error is happening. My instructor only told me this usually happens when the cart **should** exist in the localStorage, however, it **doesn't** which means the localStorage returns **NULL** to the system.

For reference to the code please check: https://gist.github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/3e15d06a8128d6ca7deaa831a7a1e52b

So, we basically create a cart called contents and we never remove empty the LocalStorage at any point in the code. How can the LocalStorage return null at some point then and cause the error?

For the init function I have this:

```
init(){
    //check localStorage and initialize the contents of CART.contents
    let _contents = localStorage.getItem(cart.KEY);
    if(_contents){
        cart.contents = JSON.parse(_contents);
     }
    else{
        cart.contents = [];
        cart.sync();
    }
},
```

**Thank you for your help in advance!**

Comment: If the element doesn't exist in local storage it will return null.  In which case `if(null)` will be false and your JSON parse will not happen.  Even if it did, JSON.parse(null) results in null.  I'm unable to replicate your error

Comment: That's not a JavaScript error, it's something coming from your school's grading software.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Yeah, it was an error coming from my school's grading software. The test had a bug apparently which got fixed.